# PyCharm and its terminal dont see module while Linux terminal does

Tags: python, module, pycharm, modulenotfounderror, gtfs

I wanted to download some live data about Trams in my city from API. I have working code, but it works only if i copy it and open linux terminal, enter python3 command and paste it there. In PyCharm i got an error(recommended option install package google didn't work):

```
from google.transit import gtfs_realtime_pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'





from google.transit import gtfs_realtime_pb2
import requests
feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()
response = requests.get('https://www.ztm.poznan.pl/pl/dla-deweloperow/getGtfsRtFile/?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0Mi56dG0ucG96bmFuLnBsIiwiY29kZSI6MSwibG9naW4iOiJtaFRvcm8iLCJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1MTM5NDQ4MTJ9.ND6_VN06FZxRfgVylJghAoKp4zZv6_yZVBu_1-yahlo&file=feeds.pb')
feed.ParseFromString(response.content)
for entity in feed.entity:
  if entity.HasField('trip_update'):
    print(entity.trip_update)
```

Comment: Maybe PyCarm is working in a virtual environment, where the specific module is not installed? Try running  `pip install <package_name>` in the terminal of PyCharm and see, if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the the google package already installed within PyCharm, it might be because the interpreter being used inside of PyCharm isn't the same one as the one in the Linux terminal itself. It would explain why it doesn't work within PyCharm itself but works within the Linux Terminal when the code is ran onto it.